# Log background jobs started in all the manually started shells?

Tags: bash, background-process, job-control

Sometimes I accidentally killed all the background jobs in a shell, for example, because [The window of a Window's program running under Wine is not in the front by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/378846/674).

I know I can use `nohup` or `disown` to protect them from being killed when killing the shell or its terminal emulator process. But if my OS is frozen, I have to restart the OS, and  neither `nohup` or `disown` can save any background process.

Is there a way to log the commands of the background jobs that are running in a shell process or all the shell processes (those manually started in particular), either periodically, or manually?

What I am thinking is to write a script, which is executed periodically in all the shell processes, and for each shell process, it will simply append the stdout output of `jobs` to a shared text file.
But I am not sure how to make it go through all the shell processes, and how to reduce any duplicate commands. I would like to log the commands in a way that I can execute the log file  directly as a shell script to rerun the commands

Thanks.

Comment: Won't always work: you could start a `bash` shell on the command line

Comment: What kind of problem can it solve to start a bash shell in a shell?

Comment: It won't solve problems, but start new ones. The jobs inside the inner shell won't be logged. My comment is that your goal is not achievable in general, even if you could sometimes find a way.

Comment: Why "The jobs inside the inner shell won't be logged"?

Comment: Why would they be logged?

Comment: BTW, `bash` is a free software, so you could study its source code and improve it to fit your needs. I don't think it is worth the pain, but YMMV

Comment: I mean if there is a way to log the jobs in the original shell, should the same way also work to log the jobs in the inner shell?

Comment: Did you consider using a batch manager, e.g. the `batch` command ?

Comment: which `batch`? I guess `bash` doesn't have a `batch` command. How do you use it here?

Comment: `batch` is part of `at`, so you need to install the `at` package (on Debian and related). But I don't really understand your issue...